# Is Cursor is class or interface in Android?

Tags: java, android, sql

According the official API, it says Cursor is public interface (API address http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html)
but when we want to operate the SQLiteDatabase, we can use the sentence like:

`Cursor cursor = db.query(....);  //db is a object of SQLiteDatabase`

method query() will return a cursor, as I know Interface can not be instantiated. So it seems contradictory.

I really got confused about that, so appreciate if anyone can answer this question.

Comment: you cannot instantiate an interface, but you *can* instantiate a class that implements it and use it as if it were an interface instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, `Cursor` is an interface and `db.query();` returns a class that implements the `Cursor` interface. That is, `db.query();` returns the implementation of a `Cursor`.

When you use the `Cursor` interface, you don't have to worry about the concrete implementation, you only know that it has methods such as `getCount()` and `close()` that you can use and that are implemented by the concrete implementation returned by `db.query();`.

In other words, `Cursor` defines the contract that any implementation must honor.

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html):

> There are a number of situations in software engineering when it is
>   important for disparate groups of programmers to agree to a "contract"
>   that spells out how their software interacts. Each group should be
>   able to write their code without any knowledge of how the other
>   group's code is written. Generally speaking, interfaces are such
>   contracts.

Comment: so，can interprete it like:`db.query` return an anonymous class which implements Cursor??

Comment: @Yangzy: No, it will return a [`SQLiteCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html), which implements the `Cursor` interface. In principle, it could return any of [the nine implementations of the `Cursor` interface in the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html), in addition to anonymous implementations or other ones that are not in the SDK.

Comment: @antonio i search the official API,and i found Cursor has 9 subclass:AbstractCursor, AbstractWindowedCursor, CrossProcessCursor, CrossProcessCursorWrapper, CursorWrapper, MatrixCursor, MergeCursor, MockCursor, SQLiteCursor。 so,because the obj which use query is an SQLiteDatabase obj,so,query will return an SQLiteCursor obj,right?

Comment: And in addition to @CommonsWare comment, any of the implementations of `Cursor` will be used the same way, as any of them _is_ a `Cursor`

Comment: @Yangzy yes, that's what @CommonsWare explained, there are several (9) implementations of `Cursor`, and `db.query` returns `SQLiteCursor`, but any of those implementations will honor the `Cursor` interface and thus, they will implement all the methods defined in `Cursor`, That's why you can use the `Cursor` returned by `db.query` without worrying about the concrete implementation. You can take a look at the explanation given in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(Java)

Comment: @antonio ,many thanks to you~~it helpful, and i find that i should better buy one english version android book so that can i understand terminology better～～～：D

Answer (score 1):

> Cursor is a interface, but query method created the implementation
>   class object. that is initialized to Cursor object.
>
> for example:
>
> List list=new ArrayList();

Comment: official api describe the function of the method "query":Query the given table, returning a Cursor over the result set.  so this method return a cursor ?or set? sorry,my english is not that good.... i can understand the example you gave.